# Boto3 delete security group by group id

Tags: python, boto3

I am trying to use Boto3 to delete security group by ID. I can't seem to figure this out so I'll give SOF a try. Here is the snippet:

```
       if sgid:
           client = boto3.client('ec2',region_name=region,aws_access_key_id=access_key,aws_secret_access_key=secret_key)
           delete_sg = ec2.delete_security_group(GroupId=sgid)
           log.info("SG Deleted")
       else:
           log.warning("No SG Provided.. But that's OK..")
```

When I run the script I get:

```
2019-03-02 19:16:54 T1000 __main__[8155] ERROR 'ec2.ServiceResource' object has no attribute 'delete_security_group'
```

Any ideas on how to fix? Let me know if more info is needed.

Comment: You have `client` defined but not `ec2`. Do you have `ec2` defined somewhere else in your code, or should `client` actually be `ec2`?

Comment: No i was originally trying to use `resource` instead of `client`. But in this particular case I am using `client`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try to call the function on client:

client.delete_security_group(GroupId=sgid)

https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/ec2.html#EC2.Client.delete_security_group

Comment: Should be called on the client *object* itself, right?